# how to display the array of values for the single field using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I need to get all the values entered in the input field. But it echoes only the first value.

ie. When I press the `+` and give some values, I need to get that value too.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".add", function() {
    var clone = '<div class="add1"><input type="text" name="selprice" /><input type = "submit"    value = "+"    class = "add" ><input type = "submit"    value = "-"    class = "remove" ></div>';
    $(this).closest('.add1').after(clone);
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).parent(".add1").remove();
  });

});
$('#package').change(function() {
  var arr = [];
  $("input.packageclass").each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).val());
    alert(arr);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="add1">
  <h6>Sales Package </h6>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="package" placeholder="Ex:34" id="package" class="packageclass">
    <input type="submit" value="+" class="add"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="add1">
    <h6>Sales Package </h6>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="package" placeholder="Ex:34" id="package" class="packageclass">
        <input type="submit" value="+" class="add">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var addInput = function(e) {
    var arr = [];
    $("input.packageclass").each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(arr);
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".add", function() {
        var clone = '<div class="add1"><input class="packageclass" type="text" name="selprice" /><input type = "submit"    value = "+"    class = "add" ><input type = "submit"    value = "-"    class = "remove" ></div>';
        $(this).closest('.add1').after(clone);
        $('.packageclass').unbind().bind('change', addInput);
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
        $(this).parent(".add1").remove();
    });

});
$('.packageclass').unbind().bind('change', addInput);
</script>
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?? arr = [1,2,3,4] right ??

Comment: Yeah sir,the same. When i click on the add button, that value should also need to echoed

Comment: will you please send me the link of fiddle,if it works for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150944/discussion-between-selvakumar-and-nishanthi).

Comment: Sorry to say this,It works but it occurs in loops. I need it at a single click

Comment: try now.. its fixed n running fine

Comment: On trying to display it on the form, comma is missing.How to solve this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151122/discussion-between-nishanthi-and-selvakumar).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.package').change(function() {
```

You are using an ID in your `input type="text"`. IDs are only used once. If you want to add the listener to all of your textfields use classes. 
In addition to that the `.change(function()` is only once called, when the dom is ready. That will be a problem too. So the change listener is not added to the generated textfields. Maybe you use something like...

```
$('.package').on('change', 'input', function() {

});
```

Comment: sorry,it is not even alerting a single input value

Comment: could you please specify? Technically I think it should work. Did you changed the select from ID to class?

Comment: but i am already having the class as packageclass, how can i add the another class to the same field

Answer (score 0):

Just using loop you can get the particular value from loop.

```
for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    arr[i];
   //work with arr[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `event delegation` to capture the events and take appropriate action.

In this, you can add a event listener to your `parent element` i.e., `click` to the `.body` in my case. When I click on the `.add` button, the event propagates and `.body` click handler gets invoked. By checking for `event.target` we can find out the origin of event and `add` or `remove` the divs.

Similary we can listen for the `change` event of the input boxes and take appropriate actions.

```js
$('#body').click(function(e) {
  if(e.target.className === 'add') {
    $('#body').append(`
      <div class="add1">
      <input type="text" name="package" placeholder="Ex:34" id="package" class="packageclass">
      <button class="add">+</button>
      <button class="remove">-</button>
    </div>
    `);
  }
  
  if(e.target.className === 'remove') {
    $(e.target).parent().empty();
  }
  
});

$('#body').change(function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  <h6>Sales Package </h6>
  <div class="add1">
    <input type="text" name="package" placeholder="Ex:34" id="package" class="packageclass">
    <button class="add">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add *class="packageclass"* to the input when creating your clone variable.

https://jsfiddle.net/289xvmu7/

```
var clone = '<div class="add1"><input type="text" name="selprice" class="packageclass"/> <input type = "submit"    value = "+"    class = "add" ><input type = "submit"    value = "-"    class = "remove" ></div>';
```

Comment: yes,i have made the changes, but it displays only the first input

Comment: No sir, fiddle also displays the same output.Will you please again check with that. My kind request